# listview checkbox trouble in android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-checkbox

i have a trouble with listview. i added a checkbox into listview to choose items. my data is coming from sqlite so i use simple cursor adapter. length of my list is aproximatley 250 lines. i am clicking a check box.when i scroll down page (list), checkbox is clicked in every 10 lines.(for example in my screen show 10 lines data when i scroll 11th lines, this row's checkbox had clicked. how can i solve this problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="TextView" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nick"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/nick"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/nick"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/phone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/name"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox"
    android:text="TextView" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is source code
    package com.example.myprojects;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class send_message extends Activity {

private ListView list;
private EditText search;
SimpleCursorAdapter adapterx;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sendmessage);

    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    search=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.search);

    loadfromdatabase();
}

private void loadfromdatabase() {
    mydb info=new mydb(this);
    info.open_read();
    Cursor c = info.getAllData();
    String[] columns = new String[] {mydb.KEY_NAME,mydb.KEY_PHONE, mydb.KEY_NICK};
    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.name,R.id.phone, R.id.nick };
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter= new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_sendmesage_rows, c, columns, to,0);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    info.close();
    }

 }
```

Comment: write a custom adapter and do processing in getView() method of that custom adapter with help of position attribute of view

Comment: You probably need to create a custom list adapter. A list adapter will reuse the row view where possible, so the state of your checkbox is indeterminate and dependent on the view being reused. Your data doesn't initialise the checkbox, so nothing currently does. A custom adapter will allow you to intialise your checkbox.

Comment: thanx your attention i will try

Answer (score 3):

If you have `CheckBox`es in `ListView` you have problem, because `ListView` reuses `View`s that aren't already visible on screen. That's why when you scroll down, it loads (a few times) that one `CheckBox` that was checked by you previously. So you can't rely on default `CheckBox`'s behaviour. What you need is:

1. Prevent user from checking `CheckBox`. You can do this by calling `cb.setEnabled(false)`, where `cb` is `CheckBox` which you are using.
2. Create your own adapter class that will extend `SimpleCursorAdapter`. In this class you will store `list` of indexes of items that are checked.
3. Override `getView()` method in your adapter class and there manually set `CheckBox` to be checked if it's position is stored in checked items array.
4. Create `OnClickListener` for your `ListView` which will take care of adding/removing checked items' positions from adapter's internal array.

**Edit:**

This would be the code of your adapter:

```
public class MySimpleCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
    public ArrayList<Integer> mItemsChecked;

    public MySimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
            String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);

        mItemsChecked = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        for(int i = 0; i < mItemsChecked.size(); i++) {
            if(mItemsChecked.get(i) == position) {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1); // Instead of checkBox1, write your name of CheckBox 
                cb.setChecked(true);
            }
        }

        return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    /* Just a handy method that will be responsible for adding/removing 
    items' positions from mItemsChecked list */ 
    public void itemClicked(int position) {
        for(int i = 0; i < mItemsChecked.size(); i++) {
            if(mItemsChecked.get(i) == position) {
                mItemsChecked.remove(i);
                return;
            }
        }
        mItemsChecked.add(position);
    }
}
```

This is `OnItemClickListener` for your `ListView`:

```
final ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1); // Your ListView name
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
        ((MySimpleCursorAdapter)lv.getAdapter()).itemClicked(position);
            lv.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged(); // Because we need to call getView() method for all visible items in ListView, so that they are updated
    }
});
```

Just remember to disable your `CheckBox` so that user can't click it.

Now you can see it as a little hack, because user doesn't click `CheckBox` at all - application sees it as clicking in specific `ListView` item, which in turn automatically checks appropriate `CheckBox` for you.

Comment: thanx piotr i will try and i will write result if i do :)

Comment: thnx so muchci will look it. i am reading this page now. maybe it will help to someone http://lalit3686.blogspot.com/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html

Comment: Made few more required adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple example that will help you to implement that scenario

http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html

Comment: page not found. why is that?

Comment: its opening in my browser please check your internet @Awais Usmani

Comment: Thanks @farrukh kindly guide me can we make it searchable?

Comment: yes you can. make an edit text to search. You hve the list of name or whatever you have implement addTextChangeListener on edit text compare the value which matches your search query make them in other list and asign that list to adapter

it is an example of it 

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/